# Run GUI program in background in Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, startup, autostart

I want to run a program (it has a gui) at startup in backgroud. As moving the program into the shell:startup folder didn´t worked to start the programm at all, I wrote a small script, which startes the programm (but not in background):

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\kilia\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\dpclat.exe"
exit
```

My issue is, that the Command Promt does not close automaticly, or the "exit" function does not work as wanted.
Optionally it would be nice if the program would start without GUI, but it that´s no must have.

Comment: Batch files execute commands line by line. The execution of each command must complete before the next command can be executed.  Your executable is still running so the `exit` command will not execute in the batch file.  The work around is to use the `START` command in your batch file. `start "Title" "C:\path to program\foo.exe"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `START` command as he mentioned it @Squashman

```
Start "" "C:\Users\kilia\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\dpclat.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nircmd exec hide X:\Path\To\Bat
```

to start your script hidden.
you should try putting your script in shell:startup again since it **SHOULD** work, but it's weird that it does not do that for you.

Comment: Thank you at first. I want to run the actual programm (.exe) in background not my script. The programm itself is very small (300kB) and its just one file without any config required. So is there maybe any solution to just make it invisible? It can be a windows service or smth? I really don´t care how to manage this, but it just should not appear on my screen ^^